# Calling external javascript file

Tags: javascript

Should the following display "Test" in a message box? If not, what changes should I make?

```
<html>
<base href="http://www.google.com"></base>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js contains:

```
alert("Test");
```

Comment: I don't think you need the language attribute.

Comment: You could have found out sooner by trying.

Comment: Have you tried to alert with script in same file (without using external js? I think no. Because you must have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: We should try to tell the reason. There is nothing wrong with the question. Why downvotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See here I've inserted this into a jsFiddle example. Next time try to just do it instead of asking a question. You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4rZCr/)

```
alert("Test");
```

is the command that does a msg box!